# Horizonatal Tab group field in drupal

Tags: drupal, content-type

Can anyone know how to create a horizontal tab group field and implement field collection within each of the created horizontal tabs in a content type.Can anyone help me in this issue.
Any tutorial links it will be useful for me.

Comment: Please select an answer!

Answer (score 1):

Please have a look at this:

http://codekarate.com/daily-dose-of-drupal/drupal-7-field-group-module

Here you can find a video tutorial on

- How to use the field group module to group fields on a Drupal node form
- How to use Horizontal field groups
- How to use Accordion field groups